# this.props.decreaseCounter is not a function : Redux attempt

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am trying to learn redux following a tutorial online but when I am almost done I ran into this error `this.props.decreaseCounter is not a function. (In '_this.props.decreaseCounter()', '_this.props.decreaseCounter' is undefined)`

I am not sure why this is the case. I just changed them to this.props after implementing the mapPropsToDispatch function in counterApp.

App.js

```
const intialState = {
  counterRedux: 0
}
const reducer = (state = intialState, action) => {
 switch(action.type){
    case 'INCREASE_COUNTER':
      return{counter:state.counterRedux+1}
    case 'DECREASE_COUNTER':
      return{counter:state.counterRedux-1}
 }
  return state;
}
const store = createStore(reducer);


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <CounterApp/>
      </Provider>
      
    );
  }
}
```

CounterApp.js

```
class CounterApp extends Component {


    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', width: 200, justifyContent: 'space-around' }}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.increaseCounter()}>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Increase</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{this.props.counter}</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.decreaseCounter()}>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>Decrease</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {
         counter: state.counterRedux
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        increaseCounter : () => dispatch({type: 'INCREASE_COUNTER'}),
        decreaseCounter : () => dispatch({type: 'DECREASE_COUNTER'}),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CounterApp)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing mapDispatchToProps to the connect function. Try changing this export from

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CounterApp)
```

to

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CounterApp)
```